# How to perform a where query on a distant relation table Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have an order with orderLines and an orderLine has a product.

I want to only retrieve orderLines where product type != Partkit.
So i want to query the Product table where type != Partkit.

How do i do this?
Order query:

```
$order = Order::with('orderLines.product')->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id)->where('is_order','0')->first();
```

What i tried:

```
$order = Order::with('orderLines.product')->whereHas('orderLines.product', function($query) {
            $query->where('type','!=', 'Partkit');
        })->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id)->where('is_order','0')->first();
```

this allways return NULL which is not what i want and isn't correct...

This is a distant relation.

any help is appreciated

Comment: What's your relationship look like on Order?  Is this supposed to be a distant relationship?  ... Edit:  Looks like this is a distant relationship, you may want to state that in your problem statement.

Comment: @Devon Yes this is a distant relation. The orderLines is a relation on order and product is a relation on orderLines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this code did what i wanted...

The query returns all, then i manually forget the orderLines i don't want.

Not the best solution but gets the job done...

```
$order = Order::with('orderLines.product')->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id)->where('is_order','0')->first();

foreach($order->orderLines as $key => $orderline) {
    if(isset($orderline->product)){
        if($orderline->product->type == "Partkit") {
            $order->orderLines->forget($key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use collection methods also to simplify your solution

Comment: Problem here is that you're potentially pulling WAY more rows than is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `has()` method.

```
$order = Order::with('orderLines.product')
            ->has('orderLines', function ($query) {
                $query->has('product', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('type', '!=', 'Partkit');
                });
            })
            ->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id)
            ->where('is_order','0')
            ->first();
```

This will select all orders, their order lines, and corresponding products, providing that the order lines have products without the type `Partkit`.

Unfortunately, you can't do a has on the relationship of a relationship, so you have to nest them like the above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't work returns `strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: Try `whereHas()` instead of `has()`

Comment: Still no luck, not the same error but doens't return the output i want.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$order = Order::with(['orderLines.product' => function($query) {
            $query->where('type','!=', 'Partkit');
        }])
        ->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id)
        ->where('is_order','0')
        ->first();
```

Please check my **updated** answer and let me know its working or not:

```
$order = Order::whereHas('orderLines.product', function($query) {
            $query->where('type','!=', 'Partkit');
        })->where('user_id',Auth()->user()->id)->where('is_order','0')->first();
```

Comment: returns all orderLines since the partkit is stored in 'product' and not on OrderLines.

Comment: @JordyGroote Let me check it

Comment: @JordyGroote Please check my updated answer may be its help for you

Comment: @JordyGroote Ok

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is the following query:

```
Order::with(['orderLines' => function($q) {

   $q->with('product')->whereHas('product', function($q2) {
      $q2->where('products.type', '!=', 'Partkit');
   });

}])->where('user_id', \Auth()->user()->id)
->where('is_order', '0')->get();
```

Assuming that your products table is called `products`, otherwise change the table name in the `$q2->where(...)` statement.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: This would return all rows, but only include the orderLines of those that have the matching products.

Comment: That's right, but that's the only thing that comes to my mind without using joins and unneeded `$with` property in the model class.